# jQuery : wrapping a string that matches a regex

Tags: jquery, regex

In a certain element, I need to select different strings that match a certain regex and wrap them with  tags. How can I do that ?

I tried :

```
var str = jQuery("#my_div").html();
var regex = "\([a-z]{2}\)";
jQuery("#my_div").html(str.replace(regex, "<span>$1</span>"));
```

.. but this wraps the whole element instead of the selected string in the element.

Comment: We need to see your regex, and a some sample HTML to be able to help you.  Likely the value of $1 isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I updated my answer, but the issue is your regex has no capture `()`, just add some parenthesis around the entire thing, so it is `(\([a-z]{2}\))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your example is you have no capturing group, change your regex to `(\([a-z]{2}\))`

Here is an example of a working regex replace in html: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/NYVWg/

```
<style>span.highlight { color: purple; }​</style>
<body>bla bla <div id="test">this (is) some text this (is) some text</div> bla bla​<body>

var oldHtml = $('#test').html();
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/(\([a-z]{2}\))/g,"<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
$('#test').html(newHtml);​
```

Comment: There's a problem with this code. If you add more instances of the pattern (for example : "this (is) some text this (is) some text this (is) some text") it will only select the first one !

Comment: @drake035, easily fixed by adding the letter g to the regex (for global)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work given that your regex has a subexpression in it.  Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hp7BR/):

HTML:

```
​<div id="my_div">foo bar my_regex foo bar</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
var str = jQuery("#my_div").html();
var regex = /(my_regex)/;
jQuery("#my_div").html(str.replace(regex, '<span class="red">$1</span>'));​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​.red {
    color : red;
}​
```