# Add tag+classname around word inside string

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add a span tag + classname around a word that contains the @ char.

My current piece of code only returns a true value if it is found, unfortunately I have no idea how to add the tag + classname. What's a proper way to do this?

```
var string = "hello @peter how are you?", substring = "@";
  if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1){
     //add span tag + classname around @peter 

  }
```

endresult should change the variable to this:

```
var string = "hello <span class='mentioned'>@peter</span> how are you?"
```

Comment: Other than [**Tony the Pony**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454), this seems to be a duplicate of [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824928/jquery-wrapping-a-string-that-matches-a-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `.replace()` method. The expression `(@\S+)` is a capturing group that matches the `@` character literally, followed by one or more non-white space character(s). Since `$1` represents the first capturing group, the match is simply replaced with `<span class='mentioned'>$1</span>`, which essentially wraps the match.

```
var string = "hello @peter how are you?";
string = string.replace(/(@\S+)/g, "<span class='mentioned'>$1</span>");

// "hello <span class='mentioned'>@peter</span> how are you?"
```

However, depending on the input, it may actually just be better to use `\w` rather than `\S`. In doing so, only the characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]` will be matched (rather than *everything* other than any non-white space character).

For instance:

```
var string = "hello @peter97... how are you?";
string = string.replace(/(@\w+)/g, "<span class='mentioned'>$1</span>");

// "hello <span class='mentioned'>@peter97</span>... how are you?"
```

Comment: in this solution I use this code in react js,
but show me the html like string :(