# Regex wrapped string does not show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function that receives a string, and then wraps all placeholders in a `span`.

```
function insertPlaceholders(text) {
    var wrappedText = text.replace(/%[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+%/g,"<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>")
    return wrappedText;
}
```

The test string is this:

```
This is a %test% string with %multiple% placeholders of which %one_is% a underscore one.
```

And if I test my regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pN5gF5/1) it matches correctly.

However, `wrappedText` returns as follows:

```
// I inserted the linebreaks so it's easy to read
<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>
<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>
<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>
<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>
<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>
```

What am I doing wrong? I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824928/jquery-wrapping-a-string-that-matches-a-regex) and it seems that I am on the right track, but I can't see where I'm screwing this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) `()` so that the value can be used in replace

```js
function insertPlaceholders(text) {
  var wrappedText = text.replace(/(%[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+%)/g, "<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>")
  return wrappedText;
}

result.innerHTML = insertPlaceholders('This is a %test% string with %multiple% placeholders of which %one_is% a underscore one.')
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis to make a capturing group

```
text.replace(/(%[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+%)/g,"<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function insertPlaceholders(text) {
            var wrappedText = text.replace(/(%[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+%)/g, "<span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='%'>$1</span>")
            return wrappedText;
        }

        result = insertPlaceholders('This is a %test% string with %multiple% placeholders of which %one_is% a underscore one.')
        $('#out').html(result)
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="in">This is a %test% string with %multiple% placeholders of which %one_is% a underscore one.</div>
 <div id="out"></div>
</body>
</html>
```